# Global Session Variable Doesn't Seem To Update It's Value - Laravel 5.8

Tags: php, laravel

I'm running a laravel app where on page load I send an ajax request to this function `reload_time()` in my controller to get the current timestamp as the page loads

```
protected function time_stamp() {
  $dt = time();
  $value = strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S", $dt);
  return $value;
}
public function reload_time() {
 session(['reload_time' => $this->time_stamp()]);
 return Response::json(session('reload_time')); 
}
```

I'm running a notification system on my app and I use this timestamp to differentiate between new notification after page reload time and older notification from page reload time.

Here are my notification functions:

```
public function get_newer_notification(Request $request) {
  $user = Auth::guard('tpuser')->user();
  $skip = $request->skip;
  $next_skip = $skip + 10;
  $notification = tpNotification::where('user_key',$user->key)
                  ->where('delete',1)
                  ->where('created_at','>', session('reload_time'))
                  ->skip($request->skip)
                  ->take(10)
                  ->orderby('created_at','desc')
                  ->get();
   $num = $notification->count();
   $num >= 10 ? $next_skip = $skip + 10 : $next_skip = $skip + $num;
   $response = [
                'collection' => $notification, 
                'next_href' => "notification/{$next_skip}/newer", 
                'reload_time' => session('reload_time')
               ];
return Response::json($response); 
}
public function get_older_notification(Request $request) {
  $user = Auth::guard('tpuser')->user();
  $skip = $request->skip;
  $notification = tpNotification::where('user_key',$user->key)
                  ->where('delete',1)
                  ->where('created_at','<=',session('reload_time'))
                  ->skip($request->skip)
                  ->take(10)
                  ->orderby('created_at','desc')
                  ->get();
   $num = $notification->count();
   $num >= 10 ? $next_skip = $skip + 10 : $next_skip = $skip + $num;
   $response = [
                'collection' => $notification, 
                'next_href' => "notification/{$next_skip}/older", 
                'reload_time' => session('reload_time')
               ];
 return Response::json($response); 
}
```

So the problem i'm facing is the fact that my `reload_time()` function returns the current timestamp but the response from my `get_newer_notification()` and `get_older_notification()` functions do not carry the same current timestamp value, but an older timestamp value from a previous page reload.

But after a couple of reloads, maybe 4 or 5, both notification functions return the same value as `reload_time()`. It almost seems like some kind of caching or slow session processing, but i'm in need of a solution.

Answer (score 1):

Is it possible to forgo all the timestamp checking and simply add a `has_been_viewed` boolean to your notifications database table?

So when a new notification is created, `has_been_viewed` will default to `false`. Then when the page is loaded/reloaded and new notifications are requested, find all notifications with `has_been_viewed = false` and set them to true before returning them.

Comment: well the thing is it is possible that some old notifications have not been viewed as well as new ones

Comment: So add a `markRead` endpoint to your API and have your frontend hit it with the notification ID when it is opened. When hit, it will set the `has_been_read` boolean on the notification to true. I know this isn't really answering your question, but it seems like a better workaround than starting to figure out and change your server's caching behavior, assuming it is possible to implement on your end.